# Deploying Google Cloud Functions using private NPM modules

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions

When you deploy a Google Cloud Function, using the Node.js runtime, you can supply your code in a `.zip` file in Google Cloud Storage (`--source=gs://...`).

I make the zip file using all the compiled source, and the `node_modules/` folder, so that GCF has everything it needs. I do this since I'm using **private** NPM modules, so `npm i` will not work inside the GCF build routine (that runs on cloud deploy inside GCP).

**Problem:**
Even if I include 100% of the needed modules in `node_modules/`, GCF still has deployment errors, since it tries to access the private NPM package repo.

If I remove the `package.json`'s `dependencies` and `devDependencies` section, GCF will fail to start, saying it cannot find the modules.

So:

1. Why can't GCF just use bundled dependencies like other tools do (e.g. GitHub Actions)
2. What is the best practice for deploying GCFs using **private** NPM modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions just released support for [private dependencies and the Node.js runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#using_private_modules).

This allows accessing private packages without passing .nomrc credentials to Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to include in your code a file called **.npmrc,** in your npm account can generate an access token with some permissions and that token is configured in the file that I mentioned above, in that way when the deploy is made, the command npm install can download the private packages.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for how to avoid including secret tokens in the deployment artifact, for the sake of security.

Comment: Maybe you can configure the token as secret in GCP and use the environment variable to download the private packages.